# Multiple file uploads to a specific folder

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, upload

I'm attempting to create a plugin on wordpress and I need to upload multiple images to a specific folder on the server...

I currently have

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple="multiple">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And this is the code that reads and should upload the files...

```
    if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
        $myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
        $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                $name = $myFile["name"][$i];
                $error_msg = $myFile["error"][$i];

                $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"][$i], $photo_dir."/".$name);

                if ($success) {
                    echo $name ." uploaded<br>";
                } else {
                    echo $error_msg;
                }

        }
    }
```

Is there a way to get it to report an error - at the moment if the file name already exists then it jsut overwrites the old version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a upload of files PHP store the files in a temporary folder.

You have to move the file from temporary folder to the folder that you want to store the files.

Here is an example using your code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {

    $myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
    $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);

    // The folder that you want to store the file
    $folderName = 'tmp/';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {

        $fileName = $myFile["name"][$i];

        $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"][$i], $folderName . $fileName);

        if ($success) {
            echo 'File ' . $fileName . ' uploaded!<br>';
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to get it to stop on an error and report it rather than just overwrite the old version if the file names are the same?

Comment: You can check if the file you're trying to upload already exists using the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function and if exists you can rename the file and make your new version